# How can I write a python decorator for a input function with type hinting?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying create the following python decorator for a function with type hint but it doesn't seem to work. It returned None instead of True. What did I do wrong?

```
    def do_nothing(func):
        def Inner_Function(*args, **kwargs):
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        return Inner_Function
    @do_nothing
    def is_cold(name: str) -> bool:
        return True
    
    g = is_cold("hi")
    print(g)
>> None
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the actual runtime behavior of your decorator, the inner function needs to `return` the result of calling the original function:

```
def do_nothing(func):
    def Inner_Function(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return Inner_Function

@do_nothing
def is_cold(name: str) -> bool:
    return True

g = is_cold("hi")
print(g)  # True
```

If you're using typechecking, you'll notice that this decorator breaks the typing of the decorated function.  If we check the type of `g` in `mypy` we'll see that it's `Any`:

```
g = is_cold("hi")
reveal_type(g)  # Revealed type is "Any"
```

To fix this, you need to add typing to your decorator to indicate that it takes a function as its argument and returns *the same type of function*:

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar

_Func = TypeVar("_Func", bound=Callable)

def do_nothing(func: _Func) -> _Func:
    def Inner_Function(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return Inner_Function  # type: ignore
```

(You can do more complex typing for `Inner_Function` to eliminate the need for the `# type: ignore`, but as far as the users of the `@do_nothing` decorator are concerned, what happens inside doesn't matter, only the signature of `do_nothing` itself.)

Now `is_cold` has its type preserved by the decorator:

```
g = is_cold("hi")
reveal_type(g)  # Revealed type is "builtins.bool"
```

Answer (score 0):

`InnerFunction` calls `func` but doesn't `return` anything. `is_cold` will return `True`, but then `InnerFunction` tosses that away and, by default, returns `None`.

Comment: how can i make it return True?

Comment: You need to fix your `InnerFunction` to `return func` and not just `func`.